# Pandas Series apply function for each value of out variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, series

I have pandas series and index array which are selected from each pandas series.

This is a toy data.

```
index = np.array([0,1,0])
row = pd.Series([np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([2,3,4]),np.array([3,4,5])])
```

I want processing data like bellow from above the toy data.

```
[row.iloc[0][0:0+2],
 row.iloc[1][1:1+2], 
 row.iloc[2][0:0+2]]

[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([3, 4])]
```

I tried to use apply function like

```
row.apply(lambda x, index: x[index:index+2])
```

But, it doesn't work.

Is there an efficient way to process that?

I have huge data so, I need an efficient method.

Comment: Please explain, using code, what "I tried to use apply function but, failed." means.

Comment: I don't use out variable in apply. so, i use this. row.apply(lambda x, index: x[index:index+2])

Comment: Now explain (in your question, good job on that) what you mean exactly by "it did not work". Try to add some analysis of why you think it did not work.

Comment: I do appreciate that you are responding to comments and making your question better BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` with a plain list comprehension;

```
[r[i:i+2] for i, r in zip(index, row)]
Out[127]:
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4]]
```